# Read two tables from database in sqlite in one grouped table view

Tags: objective-c, database, xcode, uitableview, sqlite

I have an equations list in my app and I want to have a grouped table view load one table from my sqlite database into the first section of the table view and load another table from sqlite into the second section of the table view. Ok so I know how to create and read the database from the app delegate and get my sqlite tables into two arrays that hold their content. I also know how to load one table from sqlite into a table view in xcode, but I still have a few questions. How do I set certain rows in my database to sections of my table view? Is it possible to load multiple tables from databse into one grouped table view?

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to iphone development, but upto my knowledge you can not have multiple tables in one grouped table view.

You can use if conditions or switch cases for your application to decide sections and rows.

as I m giving an example of if condition where request type is an integer.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

{
    // Return the number of sections.

```
if(RequestType == 2) 
{
    return [arrayCityNames count];
}else
{
    return 1;
}
return 1;
```

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
  // Return the number of rows in the section.

  if(RequestType == 1) 
  {
      return 1;
  }

  if(RequestType == 2) 
  {
      return 2;
  }
  if(RequestType == 3) 
  {
      return 1;

  }
  else 
  {
      // Return the number of rows in the section.
      return 1;
  }

  return 0;
  }

Comment: also use a second "cellIdentifier," but yeah that is the method to use, I dug deeper and found that solution on another persons question. lol I almost was able to pull this out of my ass, I forgot about the "switch" and "index.section"